# How to fix it?? My app getting force close when I click the button

Tags: java, android, forceclose

```
    public class Navigationmenu extends AppCompatActivity {
      private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
        private Toolbar mToolbar;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigationmenu);

            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
            mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.Open,R.string.Close );

            mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

            mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
            mToggle.syncState();

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }



        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Error.

[image]

How can I fix it?? My app is being forced to close when I click the button. Any one can help me please?

Error showing at "`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`" I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: please do not post external images - post your stuff here

Comment: Can you post the Stacktrace please?

Comment: how i can post ??

Comment: I cant post anything

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure by your pictures but it seems that you are trying to add a navigation drawer to your project. You cannot add a navigation drawer on top of pre-existing code, rather it would be more cumbersome to do it that way.

In order to get the navigation drawer working you have to add some other code rather than what Android Studio provides. If you are adding a navigation drawer than the code needs to be added to MainActivity.java rather than its own file, and then you can implement that in each other fragment class to make the navigation drawer work.

What you might try adding is something like

```
public class Navigationmenu extends AppCompatActivity {
   //Try this piece here
    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigationmenu);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new  ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.Open,R.string.Close );

        mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();


        //Try adding this to the code
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view); //Declared in activity_main.xml
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

If you are trying to make a Navigation Drawer with fragments, look to this complete MainActivity.java I have made, and note that everything in Navigation drawers runs on Fragments.

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, LoginFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {



    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.main) {
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.login) {
            LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
        //Leave blank
    }
}
```